# React-native-image-picker camera doesn't open

Tags: android, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I need to add image picker in my app. I've created small class for image picker logic:

```js
import {launchImageLibrary, launchCamera} from 'react-native-image-picker';

export default class ImagePickerService {
  static openPickerLibrary(
    setImageUrl: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string | null | undefined>>,
    setModalVisible: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>,
  ) {
    launchImageLibrary(
      {mediaType: 'photo', includeBase64: true},
      (response: any) => {
        if (response.didCancel) {
          console.log('User cancelled image picker');
        } else if (response.error) {
          console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
        } else {
          setImageUrl(`data:image/jpeg;base64,${response.base64}`);
          setModalVisible(false);
        }
      },
    );
  }

  static openPickerCamera(
    setImageUrl: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string | null | undefined>>,
    setModalVisible: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>,
  ) {
    launchCamera({mediaType: 'photo', includeBase64: true}, (response: any) => {
      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else {
        setImageUrl(`data:image/jpeg;base64,${response.base64}`);
        setModalVisible(false);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Then I call these methods this way:

```js
<ModalButton
  label="Take photo"
  onPress={() =>
    ImagePickerService.openPickerCamera(setImageUrl, setPickerVisible)
  }
/>
<ModalButton
  label="Choose photo"
  onPress={() =>
    ImagePickerService.openPickerLibrary(setImageUrl, setPickerVisible)
  }
/>
```

Picker library works great. But picker camera doesn't open. Only the modal window closes and nothing else. Also there aren't any errors in console.

I don't understand why this happens. I have all permissions in AndroidManifest. Also I have tried this string and it didn't help:

```js
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Also I have tried these features and they also didn't help:

```js
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with `react-native-camera`.

Comment: If you have a follow-on question, please ask a new one, or update your question and delete this answer.